# Example of the expression in the context

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-in-context

Can someone provide me with the context ( not the biblical one) for the expression ' Poor as Lazarus' because it is a little bit of a challegne for me to find one.

Comment: There is no "context" other than the biblical one. In any case, I personally don't recall ever encountering this "expression" before. It just so happens that Lazarus was a ***beggar*** (and thus by definition, "poor"), but the only reason Anglophones today know or care about him is because supposedly Jesus brought him back to life after he (Lazarus) died. Consequently, one of my computers is named "Lazarus" on my home network because of the number of times it's been fixed / brought back to life after developing a serious fault.

Comment: In the first stanzas of ‘The Other Side,’ the speaker, who is Heaney in the 70s as he looks back on his youth, begins by describing the actions of a stranger on the poet’s family’s land. Young Heaney listened in and watched as another person, “laid his shadow / on the stream”. This person, who was named by Heaney as Johnny Junkin later, was moving through the “sedge” or wetland grasses and marigold flowers before he said out loud “It’s as poor as Lazarus, that ground”.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Not the same Lazarus, I'm afraid! Jesus tells the story of the rich man and the beggar Lazarus in Luke ch. 16. The friend he brought back to life was Lazarus of Bethany, brother of Martha and Mary.

Comment: @KateBunting: Just goers to show how much I know about it! But I really do have a PC dubbed "Lazarus" for the reason specified, and from *my* point of view Lazarus (at least, ***one*** of them) is only famous for being brought back to life. But even if there is another biblical background, OP says that's not what he's looking for anyway. Whatever - it sounds more like an exercise in ancient history rather than "learning English".

Comment: @KateBunting It might be helpful to your fallible fellow commentators to know what other fields you are expert in before we betray our frailties.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I don't know why you're being so sarcastic. I know my Bible reasonably well, and the raising of Lazarus (supposedly a real person) is in John Ch. 11. The speaker in Heaney's poem must be referring to the pauper Lazarus (supposedly a fictional character) in Luke 16.

Comment: @KateBunting Forgive me. You have me wrong. Sarcasm was the last thing on my mind. My comment, however misplaced, was intended by way of an indirect compliment, and please take it as such.  Your answers and comments are admirable. I wish there were more like them.

Comment: @RonaldSole - In that case, my apologies and thanks for the compliment. I thought you were accusing me of setting up as a theological expert (which I am not!).

Comment: @KateBunting Although we're not in the habit of upvoting colleagues on this site, you're welcome. I love crisp prose. Ironically, majored in Biblical Studies a very long time ago.

Comment: @RonaldSole - crisp prose really 'floats my boat', if I may use a modern expression.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any non-Biblical context. See the story of ['Dives' and Lazarus](https://religion.fandom.com/wiki/Lazarus_and_Dives#:%7E:text=Dives%20and%20Lazarus%2C%20also%20called,a%20poor%20beggar%20named%20Lazarus.), which inspired a folk song as well as paintings.